# Combine multiple strings in array 1 to form array 2

Tags: ruby

I have an array of strings "A" and a target string "B". The B string 
contains only characters from a to z and does not contain spaces. I need a ruby function 
that returns the array of strings which represents all possible ways to form B from elements of Array A. The order in which combinations are returned is irrelevant. Words from A can be used multiple times.

Example:

```
A = [‘x’, ‘y’, ‘z’, 'yz',‘xy’, ‘xyz’] 

B = ‘xyz’ 

method(A, B) => [x y z, x yz, xyz, xy z]
```

I looked into permutation method but can't get it to work.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what've tried so far, and if possible an example of what the output should look like?

Comment: A = [‘x’, ‘y’, ‘z’, ‘yy’, ‘yz’] 
B = ‘xyyz’ 
method_name(A, B) => [‘x y yz’, ‘xy yz’, etc]

Ive tried scanning and mapping - so frustrating! Im new to Ruby and I always have such a hard time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a recursive solution that doesn't iterate through the permutations:

```
def find_possible_combinations( list, str )
  list.select { |a| str.start_with? a }.map do |a|
    if a == str
      [a]
    else
      find_possible_combinations( list-[a], str.slice(a.length..-1) )
        .map { |c| "#{a} #{c}" }
    end
  end.flatten
end

puts "#{find_possible_combinations( %w( x y z yz xy xyz ), 'xyz' )}"
```

Output:

```
["x y z", "x yz", "xy z", "xyz"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A = %w[x y z yz xy xyz] 
B = "xyz"
SIZE = B.size

def combos
  (1..SIZE).inject([]) {|c, n| c.concat(combos_by_size(n))}.reject(&:empty?)
end

# Select all combinations of size n having SIZE characters
def combos_by_size(n)
  A.combination(n).to_a.inject([]) {|c, a| c.concat(matching_combos(a)) if a.join.size == SIZE; c}.reject(&:empty?)
end


# Select all matching combinations using all elements of array a
def matching_combos(a)
  a.permutation.to_a.select {|p| p.join == B}
end

combos # => [["xyz"], ["x", "yz"], ["xy", "z"], ["x", "y", "z"]]
```